# How to download SSL certificate that was imported into an Azure Function app?

Tags: azure-functions, ssl-certificate

Last year I uploaded a pfx certificate to a consumption-based Azure Function app. Currently, I don't have access to it anywhere else. Is it possible to download this pfx file in any way? I could not see this option on the portal. Tried FTPing into the app and there was nothing there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround is to download it from your KUDU console. Steps to download your certificate.

1. Add `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` to * from your Application settings.
2. Navigate to your KUDU console from **Advanced Tools >> Go >> Debug Console >> Powershell**.
3. `Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My` lists the certificate loaded in current user.
4. Then you can export the same to your wwwroot folder using

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\currentuser\my | 
   Select-Object -first 1 | 
   Export-Certificate -FilePath D:\home\site\wwwroot\certificate.pfx -Force
   ```
5. Now you can directly download from  D:\home\site\wwwroot\certificate.pfx

   [image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Export SSL Certificate from Azure Web App](http://reza-aghaei.com/export-ssl-certificate-from-azure-web-app/)